# How to configure ecommerce tracking in my wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I want to enable ecommerce tracking in my wordpress site that reflects in google analytics 4. By default, I have the code integrated in wordpress for GA4. But now would like to add ecommerce tracking as well.

How should I do?
Do I need google tag manager for that?
If yes, what will happen with the existing GA4 tracking code?

Answer (score 0):

You need only create dataLayer for ecommerce events. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/ecommerce?client_type=gtag
For example for product page view dataLayer code like:

```
gtag("event", "view_item", {
  currency: "USD",
  value: 7.77,
  items: [
    {
      item_id: "SKU_12345",
      item_name: "Stan and Friends Tee",
      affiliation: "Google Merchandise Store",
      coupon: "SUMMER_FUN",
      discount: 2.22,
      index: 0,
      item_brand: "Google",
      item_category: "Apparel",
      item_category2: "Adult",
      item_category3: "Shirts",
      item_category4: "Crew",
      item_category5: "Short sleeve",
      item_list_id: "related_products",
      item_list_name: "Related Products",
      item_variant: "green",
      location_id: "ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo",
      price: 9.99,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ]
});
```